# Check if timestamps column values are in data range for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I would like to achieve the following with python pandas.

Suppose I have the following tables:

Events table

```
id event capture_date 
1  Up   '2021-01-10'  
1  Down '2021-03-25'
       ...  
1  Up   '2021-08-01'  
2  Up   '2021-06-02'  
2  Down '2021-09-15'  
2  Up   '2021-11-03' 
2  Down '2021-11-05'
       ...
10  Down'2020-06-02'  
10  Up  '2020-09-15'  
10  Down'2021-10-03' 
10  Up  '2021-11-09'
```

Activity table

```
id activity_date 
1  '2021-01-12'  
1  '2021-03-28'  
1  '2021-08-04'  
2  '2021-06-30'  
2  '2021-11-01'  
2  '2021-11-03'
10 '2020-01-03'
```

For each id group, I would like to add a third column to the "Activity" table" that depends on the "capture_date" from the "Events" table. For example, for id =1: if the the activity_date falls between Up and Down events, then write 0, otherwise 1. And this should be done for every id group.

Thanks!

Comment: So for events is multiple `Up` values per `id`?  It is correct? Only only one `Up` and `Down` ?

Comment: you have multiple Up events each group

Comment: Yes @jezrael, you can have multiple `Up` values and even multiple `Down` values for each id.

Comment: correct @sammywemmy, and `Down` too!

Comment: @jezrael not sure if I understand your question. Ideally there will always be a `Down` after `Up` and so on. I wanted to solve this problem first and then eventually explore the scenario where you could have a sequence like the following: `Up` - `Down` - `Down` - `Up`.

Comment: Sorry I don't get this: Why missing in input data?

Comment: OK, my problem of question is missing defined intervals if values `Up - Down - Down - Up` ? For missing `Down` like in sample `Up - Down - Up` is used first or second `Up` ? In sample data missing this scenarions.

Comment: So next problem, some values of `Down` are less like `Up` for `id=10` ? Still missing logic of specified pairs up-down

Comment: @jezrael apologies if the question is not clear. I have amended the sample data, hope it make sense now. Think of `Up` and `Down` as events for someone switching from Freemium to Premium plan  and vice versa, while using an app. So `Up` is for upgrading  and `Down` is for downgrading.

Comment: @jezrael you might not have recorded the event for some users. In this case, for id=10, I don't have the recording of the first upgrade (or sign up if you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a package called [`staircase`](https://www.staircase.dev) which is built on pandas and numpy for step functions.  The data you have describes step functions.  The functions step "Up" and "Down" as you have labelled it.  We'll assume this means stepping up to a value of 1 and down to a value of 0, and then switch these values in line with your spec.

**setup**

```
import pandas as pd

events = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
        "event":["Up", "Down", "Up", "Up", "Down", "Up"],
        "capture_date":["2021-01-10", "2021-03-25", "2021-08-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-09-15", "2021-11-03"],
    }
)

activities = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
        "activity_date":["2021-01-12", "2021-03-28", "2021-08-04", "2021-06-30", "2021-11-01", "2021-11-03"],
    }
)

events["capture_date"] = pd.to_datetime(events["capture_date"])
activities["activity_date"] = pd.to_datetime(activities["activity_date"])
```

**solution**

A stepfunction is represented by the [`staircase.Stairs`](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/Stairs.html) class.  It takes vectors of start and end times (up and down in your case).  These times do not need to be paired, or equal in count.  If there is no matching "down" after an "up" then this simply means the step function will continue on with a value of 1 indefinitely as it heads towards infinity. .  Likewise, if there is no matching "up" then the step function will have a value of 1 indefinitely as it heads towards negative infinity.  We'll group the `events` dataframe by `id` and use the data to construct a step function for each id

```
import staircase as sc

stepfunctions = events.groupby("id").apply(lambda df: 
    sc.Stairs(
        start=df.query("event == 'Up'").capture_date,
        end=df.query("event == 'Down'").capture_date,
    )
)
```

`stepfunctions` is a `pandas.Series`, indexed by `id` and the values are `staircase.Stairs` objects

```
id
1    <staircase.Stairs, id=2209708361352>
2    <staircase.Stairs, id=2209708432264>
dtype: object
```

To handle the case where there are `id` values in `events` which do not appear in `activities` we'll manually add zero-valued step functions for these ids

```
for i in pd.Index(activities["id"]).difference(stepfunctions.index):
    stepfunctions[i] = sc.Stairs()
```

You can do many things with step functions, including visualising

```
stepfunctions[1].plot(style="hlines")
```

[image]

We can sample the step functions eg

```
stepfunctions[1].sample("2021-01-12", include_index=True)
```

which gives you

```
2021-01-12    1
dtype: int64
```

These step functions are currently 1 between up and down, and 0 between down and up.  It seems like you want the opposite.  This can be done by flipping these boolean valued step functions with [`staircase.Stairs.invert`](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/api/staircase.Stairs.invert.html#staircase.Stairs.invert)

Putting it all together, with the help of `pandas.concat` we have

```
result = (
    pd.concat(
        [stepfunctions[id].invert().sample(df["activity_date"], include_index=True) for id, df in activities.groupby("id")]
    )  # a pandas.Series
    .astype(int)  # convert integer floats
    .rename("Activity")  # renames the Series to your required name
    .reset_index() # turns activity date from index to column
    .assign(id=activities["id"])  # inserts id column
)
```

`result` will be a dataframe

```
  activity_date  Activity  id
0    2021-01-12         0   1
1    2021-03-28         1   1
2    2021-08-04         0   1
3    2021-06-30         0   2
4    2021-11-01         1   2
5    2021-11-03         0   2
```

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: This looks great! I did not know this staircase package. When some ids in activities do not exist in event table, I get a KeyError. I am looking for a nice way to take in count this case with your solution.

Comment: did you mean `.assign(id=activities["id"])` ?

Comment: @gdc yeh did a rename and missed a couple of places. Have fixed, thanks for the pick up.

Comment: @gdc I've made an edit to handle the case of missing ids in events table

Comment: Thank you for fixing that! I am testing this with messier data, will this solution handle this case? Suppose I change the event column in events dataframe like this:                      
`  "event":["Up", "Down", "Down", "Up", "Down", "Up"]`

Comment: In your example is there an "Up" missing between the two "Down"?  Is that what you mean by messy data?

Comment: Ideally `Up` and `Down` should always alternate, unfortunately you could end up having  `Up` , `Up`, `Down` or `Up` , `Down`, `Down`  or even `Down`, `Down`, `Down`! Of course the sequence can have any length, doesn't need to have three elements only.

Comment: I'm not sure any approach to your question will work straight out of the box without some sort of data cleaning first, and deciding how to handle sequences which aren't alternate.

Comment: Yes I agree. Indeed having the same events in sequence would not mean much for my case. Thanks for this. I think I will thoroughly test your solution and will think of a solution that might work for bigger size data. I am just worried that the concatenate function you suggest to create the `result` data frame might have performance issues. Thanks again!

Comment: You could alternatively groupby on 'alternatives ' and apply a function which filters creates and samples a stepfunction. You would avoid using the concat method but I'm not sure if you'd see improvement in speed or not.